# NameError: name 'session' is not defined

Tags: python, rembg

I want to remove the background and replace it with a white background and resize it for images in a folder. I only get an error.

**I got the following code:**

```
from PIL import Image
import rembg

def process(session, image, *, size=None, bgcolor='white'):
    "session is a rembg Session, and image is a PIL Image"
    if size is not None:
        image = image.resize(size)
    else:
        size = image.size
    result = Image.new("RGB", size, bgcolor)
    out = rembg.remove(image, session=session)
    result.paste(out, mask=out)
    return result

from pathlib import Path

for path_in in Path(r'C:\Users\test').glob('*.jpg'):
    path_out = path_in.parent / f"{path_in.stem}-out.png"
    if path_out.exists():
        continue
    with Image.open(path_in) as img:
        out = process(session, img, size=(700, 700), bgcolor='#FFFFFF')
        out.save(path_out)
```

**Error**

```
NameError: name 'session' is not defined
```

on this line:

```
out = process(session, img, size=(700, 700), bgcolor='#FFFFFF')
```

Would appreciate the help!

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. debug your code before posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Only issue here is undefined `session`, you need identify with this  `session = rembg.new_session()`. After that you can take output.

Comment: How would I place this in the code?

Comment: you can place anywhere but example => with Image.open(path_in) as img: <here>